# How to identify the process is started manually or from Task Scheduler?

Tags: c#, winforms, scheduled-tasks

I have a win form application which generates some PDF files. Now I have to create a task in scheduler to run the application on every day on specified time. Now what I have to do is, I need to run the application manually. While its running manually need to show some extra results to user. So how can I identify the application run by scheduler or manually?

Comment: When initiating by scheduler pass a command line parameter. e.g. `--showNoUI`. Then you can distinguish between the two.

Comment: Simple solution: let your graphical application read parameters, then modify the scheduled task to run your program passing a specified parameter to determine it.

Comment: @ElektroStudios can you give me one example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here You Go

1. Go to properties of project set some command line arguments. This will be for knowing manually (set for both release and debug)
   [image]
2. Now go to Task Scheduler and set parameters like given below
   [image]
3. Now when it runs from exe or scheduler this argument will come as parameter

   **Code Sample**

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
   }
   ```

Comment: Its working fine when i am running an application in vs. after running the exe file from installed system, getting exception, I am not able to access the **args** its empty. May i know why its happen like this

Comment: Check if they are coming in scheduler. If they are coming in scheduler your job will be done. Bit busy

Answer (score 0):

You may use current directory as an indicator:

```
if (Environment.CurrentDirectory == Application.StartupPath)
{
    // Started from Start menu
}
else if (Environment.CurrentDirectory == Environment.SystemDirectory)
{
    // Started by Task Scheduler
}
```

It works when current directory ("Start in") is set to application directory in start menu shortcut and *not* set in Task Scheduler action. This is pretty common.

[Application Directory set as current directory in start menu shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKVqK.png)

**Remark:**
Ramankingdom's answer is preferable. Though, if for some (organizational) reason you cannot use command-line parameters, this is an additional option.